# How to manually pass an objective-c block to objc_msgSend

Tags: objective-c, delphi, objective-c-blocks

I have the following function that successfully calls a method that requires a block as parameter:

```
OBJC_EXPORT
void testsendmsg(void *block)
{
    [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:1024 handler:block];
}
```

Now I'm trying to call this method using objc_msgSend. By looking at the disassembly of the above function I found out that I need to pass an additional "0" as parameter before the block. With that, the following code appears to work:

```
OBJC_EXPORT
void testsendmsg(void *block)
{
    objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSEvent"), sel_getUid("addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:"), 1024, 0, block);
}
```

But what is the meaning of this "0"? Is it always a "0" or could it happen that I need to pass a different value?

My ultimate goal is to call `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler` from Delphi. So just changing `(void *block)` to something else or using the official block syntax like `handler:^(NSEvent *event){ return nil; };` is not an option for me.

Comment: The RTL can do this for you in Macapi.OCBlocks.pas. You can either use the options the unit provides, or just use the GetObjCBlock/FreeBlock functions and provide your own _objcblockcallbackallpointer procedure.

Comment: I already had a look at that unit. But if I read that code correctly, then GetObjCBlock is only implemented when {$IFDEF CPUARM} is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should never call `objc_msgSend` directly, because it has the wrong type. It's not a real function; it is a trampoline that passes execution to the destination IMP, so it acts as a function of the type of the destination IMP. Therefore, you must first cast it to the function type of the destination IMP before calling it, so the the compiler will use the correct calling convention for the destination IMP. This is how you would call it if your code were in Objective-C:

```
id (*f)(id, SEL, NSEventMask, NSEvent *(^)(NSEvent *)) =
    (id (*)(id, SEL, NSEventMask, NSEvent *(^)(NSEvent *)))objc_msgSend;
id result = f([NSEvent class],
              @selector(addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:),
              NSKeyDown, block);
```

It seems that you need to avoid Objective-C or block syntax (which is an extension of C) or all Cocoa variables. That's fine. I'm not sure whether you can use the enum `NSEventMask`, but assuming you can't, you can see [from the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSEventMaskFromType) that its underlying type is `unsigned long long`. So you would do

```
id (*f)(id, SEL, unsigned long long, void *) =
    (id (*)(id, SEL, unsigned long long, void *))objc_msgSend;
id result = f(objc_getClass("NSEvent"),
              sel_getUid("addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:"),
              1024, block);
```

That also explains why you think there is an extra "0"; the unsigned long long takes two processor words.

Comment: The trick was indeed that NSEventMask must be `unsigned long long`. So the final solution is:

`type NSEventMask = UInt64;`

`R := objc_msgSend(objc_getClass('NSEvent'), sel_getUid('addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:'), NSEventMask(NSKeyDownMask), block);`

Comment: @SebastianZ: You still shouldn't be calling `objc_msgSend` directly. `objc_msgSend`'s declaration is fake -- it's declared to take varargs, but that's not actually what happens; it acts like the destination IMP. The calling conventions for varargs are not always the same as for an equivalent multi-argument function. For example, in varargs, `float` are promoted to `double`, and `char` and `short` promoted to `int` I believe; whereas for normal arguments, this may or may not happen, depending on architecture.

Comment: @SebastianZ: And for struct returns, using `objc_msgSend_stret`, the calling conventions are completely different (struct returns work by passing a pointer to the struct as an argument); and casting to the right function type works correctly. It may happen to work in this example using the varargs type, because `int`s and pointers and `long long`s are passed the same way on this architecture in both cases, but you should not depend on it, and on a different architecture or using different types it may not work.